# Windows 10 Automatic zoom

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, acer-aspire, zoom, mouse-wheel

Today, when I turned on my laptop, after a few minutes Windows automatically start zooming in and out. For example, when I scroll some windows like explorer, Chrome or any other application it starts zooming in and out.

I restarted Windows 10 several times but the issue remains the same. I didn't install any new update or any other software, computer was working fine a day ago.

Laptop model: Acer Aspire v3-772G

OS: Windows 10 Anniversary update

Comment: Sounds to me like one of your Ctrl keys are stuck. Try hitting Shift + Esc - If task manager opens, one of them are stuck.

Comment: I tried ctrl+Shift+Esc and task manager opens, either issue itself resolved or will happen after few mintues

Comment: Your <ctrl> key is getting stuck. Clean your keyboard.